# jQuery pretty photo plugin doesn't show thumbnails in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

I'm using jquery pretty photo plugin as my image gallery. but when I open a photo, it works good but doesn't show the thumbnails, instead shows the default background defined in its css:

My Result:
[image]

My Desired Result:
[image]

My HTML:

```
<ul class="hover_thumb_wrap">
    <li class="hover_thumb_unit">
        <a rel="prettyPhoto[18]" class="imgwrap" title="Item Title" href="http://placehold.it/800x600" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img width="50" height="50" alt="Item Thumbnail Alt" class="attachment-50x50" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hover_thumb_unit">
        <a rel="prettyPhoto[18]" class="imgwrap" title="Item Title" href="http://placehold.it/400x500" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img width="50" height="50" alt="Item Thumbnail Alt" class="attachment-50x50" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

My Javascript:

```
jQuery("#item-wrap a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            animationSpeed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
            padding: 15, /* padding for each side of the picture */
            opacity: 0.7, /* Value betwee 0 and 1 */
            showTitle: false, /* true/false */
            allowresize: true, /* true/false */
            counter_separator_label: '/', /* The separator for the gallery counter 1 "of" 2 */
            //theme: 'dark_square', /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square */
            hideflash: false, /* Hides all the flash object on a page, set to TRUE if flash appears over prettyPhoto */
            modal: false, /* If set to true, only the close button will close the window */
            callback: function() {
                var url = location.href;
                var hashtag = (url.indexOf('#!prettyPhoto')) ? true : false;
                if (hashtag) location.hash = "!";
            } /* Called when prettyPhoto is closed */,
            social_tools : ''
      });
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Comment: @MichałRybak, its hard to make one, please give your guess.

Comment: debugging is about analyzing code, not guessing where the error is. You can import external resources to jsFiddle wthout a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is prettyPhoto validate your image url.
Validate image url end with jpg|jpeg|png|gif.
So solution is:

## 1: change your image url http://placehold.it/800x600 => http://placehold.it/800x600.jpg

## 2: Edit file: jquery.prettyPhoto.js (unzip version) line 763: comment this code

```
if(!pp_images[i].match(/\b(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)\b/gi)){
                    classname = 'default';
                    img_src = '';
                }else{
                    classname = '';
                    img_src = pp_images[i];
                }
```

and replace with

```
classname = '';
img_src = pp_images[i];
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto["18"]']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'pp_default',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: false});
});

</script>
```

Add this script in your header file or any other suitable js file.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
overlay_gallery:true,
overlay_gallery_max:30
```

Comment: $.prettyPhoto.initialize = function() {
    ...
    // Put the SRCs, TITLEs, ALTs into an array.
    pp_thumbs = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return $(n).find('img').attr('src');}) : $.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    pp_images = ...

Comment: $.prettyPhoto.open = function(event) {
    ...
    pp_thumbs = $.makeArray(arguments[0]);
    pp_images = ... 
     
function _build_overlay(caller){
    for (var i=0; i < pp_thumbs.length; i++) {
       if(!pp_thumbs[i].match(/\b(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)\b/gi)){
          ...
       }else{
          classname = '';
          //img_src = pp_images[i];
          img_src = pp_thumbs[i]
          ...